# How to avoid `if __name__ == '__main__'` in Python multiprocessing?

Tags: python, parallel-processing, fork, python-multiprocessing, spawn

When using the library `multiprocessing` in Python, we know that `if __name__ == '__main__'` is necessary to fork children processes correctly from the parent. Otherwise there can be a RuntimeError like this:

```
        An attempt has been made to start a new process before the
        current process has finished its bootstrapping phase.

        This probably means that you are not using fork to start your
        child processes and you have forgotten to use the proper idiom
        in the main module:

            if __name__ == '__main__':
                freeze_support()
                ...

        The "freeze_support()" line can be omitted if the program
        is not going to be frozen to produce an executable.
```

But is it possible to avoid `if __name__ == '__main__'`? What if I am writing a library that spawns multiple processes? Is it possible to eliminate the necessity for users to write `if __name__ == '__main__'` and deal with tedious details about multiprocessing?
I can write `if __name__ == '__main__':` inside my library, but in this way the user's code would run multiple times in my multiple processes.

Comment: Your library should hide its functionality inside a function or class and not perform those tasks when you `import` it.